# How to improve the performance of drawing a large polygon using SkiaSharp?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I have a contour that has about 20,000 points that I'm drawing using `SkiSharp`. It's a bit sluggish (200 ms), and I'm wondering if there are any performance improvements I could make to my code:

```
var path = new SKPath();
path.AddPoly(contour.Select(p => p.ToSKPoint()).ToArray());  // contour is Point[]
canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
```

When my view is zoomed out, it's probably not even possible to see that many points, so one possible optimization I thought about is to filter out points uniformly (like only keep one every 10 or 100 points).

Comment: definitely reduce the amount of data - there are smoothing algorithms you can use, but I'd suggest starting by just eliminating 90% of the data and seeing how that changes performance

Comment: @Jason Reducing the number of points definitely helps, so perhaps I can do that when the user is zoomed out (and can't notice the missing points). When zoomed in, however, I want to show every point. I've noticed that when zoomed in, performance improves again (since only a subset of points need to be drawn).

Comment: @redcurry in videogames that's called level of detail (LOD). The Problem is very similar, far away geometry doesn't need to be as detailed as near one. May you find some ideas which might help. If you've found a solution, please answer your own question, so others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 3):

I’ve improved my rendering time from 6ms to 1ms by using SKGLView instead of SKCanvasView.
They have the same API, and are very easy to exchange.

Also, like you’ve said dynamically reducing the amount of points depending on zoom level. Aka LOD - Level of Detail.

And if feasible, disable AntiAliasing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the `SKPath` only once and use it again and again. That could help.